# Adodb and Kohana 3

Tags: ms-access, kohana, kohana-3

I want to connect to a MSaccess database using adodb. I dunno how to even start with such problem. Is there anyone who can tell me?  I need some easy tips.

Comment: Kohana 3 supports PDO, I believe it can connect to MS-Access databases, take a look at this page: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html and search for "access"

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start is to probably check the doc at this link:

http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm

The manual for ADODB has some examples specifically for MS Access